# Trouble getting a nested menu item to show up in Drupal 7 module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a tab which I attach to nodes; it works just fine.

I have a sub-tab which I want to place beneath that tab. It does not show up.

Here is my menu definition related to the problem:

```
// Parent tab, attached to nodes.
$items['node/%node/layout'] = array(
'title' => 'Parent tab',
'description' => 'tab that is attached to the node, same level as edit tab',
'page callback' => 'my_callback',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' => true, // To test.
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
'weight' => 200,
'file' => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
);
// Child tab, beneath parent tab.
$items['node/%node/layout/fields'] = array(
'parent' => 'node/%/layout',
'title' => 'child tab',
'description' => 'child tab, underneath parent tab',
'page callback' => 'my_child_callback',
'page arguments' => array(1),
'access callback' => true, // To test.
'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
'file' => 'mymodule.admin.inc',
);
```

Thanks in advance for any help you might offer.

Comment: As far as I know local tasks will only show as tabs if there's more than one of them. You might try adding another item to test that out (e.g. `$items['node/%node/layout/test'] = array(...`). There's always the `MENU_LOCAL_ACTION` option which will add a link to the top of the parent page rather than a tab

Comment: You are correct. Thanks! @Clive, you should post that as an answer, so I can accept it and you can get magic internet points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Clive pointed out in a comment to my question: MENU_LOCAL_TASK requires at least two items.